# Adding a Purchase Order via QuickBooks API from c# online using .NET IPP QBOV3 SDK

Tags: c#, .net, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to post a purchase order to QuickBooks online using the c# .NET IPP QBOV3 SDK.

I have managed to get Invoices posting OK, so I thought adding an purchase order, would be very similar. However, this is not the case. (at least it doesnt seem to be - correct me if I am wrong)

I can not find any working c# examples of this, so was hoping someone could set me in the right direction.

The only question I could find on SO is - [how to add purchase order with QBO rest api v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461431/how-to-add-purchase-order-with-qbo-rest-api-v3-0)

However, this code just gives a "Bad request" error, which is not very helpful at all.

Even if someone could point me in the right direction on how I can view the JSON request I am sending, and how I can view the response would be a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code mentioned in the link in the question is OK. 
The problem I had was the item itself - in the item list there is a tick box, which states if the item is sold or purchased - I had the tick box to say it was sold, silly mistake. (obviously should of been set to the item is purchased)

Having this ticked on, was enough to stop the PO from being created.