# Any reasonably complete examples of .NET v3 SDK for QBO (IPP)

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have searched and searched and find it odd that I am unable to locate any reasonably comprehensive source code examples, on the intuit developer platform or anywhere else, to see how the .NET v3 SDK for QBO is used in a best-practices sense.  Anyone know the existence of ANY kind of examples that would be helpful?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic"

Comment: Hmmmmm.  This question just put on hold as off-topic.  While I understand the impulse, Intuit seems to be routing folks to stack exchange for technical help from their main support dashboard at https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Overview for questions.

Comment: Don't waste your time on the 'TimeTracker' example solution they provide. Some of the worst code I have ever seen. I am sure it was written by a co-op student who was trying to mix in 7 different design patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at this link.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/0002_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

From the following thread, you'll get a invoice create example.
[how to add invoice or sales receipt quickbooks rest api v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680986/how-to-add-invoice-or-sales-receipt-quickbooks-rest-api-v3-0/)

Hope it will be useful.

Thanks

Comment: I am really grateful I got your reply.... thanks.  The first link I have pored over many times.  The second is really helpful, and not something I came up with on searching Stack Exchange.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that it is helpful :) . If possible, please mark the post as ans. Thanks