# Intuit .NET SDK - Invoice Sales Item Line Detail - Why Amount Required

Tags: c#, asp.net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

RE: [Quickbooks Invoice Object](http://ippdocs.intuit.com/0025_QuickBooksAPI/0050_Data_Services/030_Entity_Services_Reference/Invoice#SalesItemLineDetail).

I am building a shipping system for a client and would like to create invoices in quickbooks using the SDK ([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542914/ipp-net-sdk-for-quickbooks-v3-0-create-invoice-error-bad-request/18622269#18622269)).

It seems like your financials system, i.e. Quickbooks, should be in charge of the pricing for items if your invoice detail type is of a SaleItemLine. Basically, I'd think that this means that your are going to reference your sales item, which in Quickbooks contains the price and you may also have price levels set up for a customer. So I'd think you'd just pass a reference to the Sales Item and then a Quantity, and then Quickbooks would calculate the unit and line price based off of that and the pricing level set up for that customer (assuming you are referencing a customer). So why do you have to supply (it is required in the API) the Line_Header.Amount value (which is the line amount = item's unit price * line quantity)? Why should your system know that? Why is that not calculated by Quickbooks?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Line_Header.Amount is NOT required. If you don't pass it, it will use the Item Pricing in Quickbooks and it will also take into account any Pricing Levels setup for that customer as configured in Quickbooks.