# How to set TotalAmount for SalesReciept

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm using QBO Rest API V3 SDK and trying to create a deposit onto an account.  It seems there isn't a deposit transaction anymore, so am trying to use a SalesReciept to do so.

The call is succeeding and the transaction is created however the SalesReciept is returned with a TotalAmount of zero.  When I look at the QBO application it shows a 0 Deposit amount as well.

I noticed there was a UnitPrice on the API, but was missing from the SDK, so I hand crafted a web request and it still came back with a 0.

If there is another approach I should take let me know.

```
var deposit = new SalesReceipt()
{
    DepositToAccountRef = new ReferenceType()
    {
        Value = "1",
        name = "MyAccount"
    },
    TxnDate = transaction.TransactionDate,
    TxnDateSpecified = true,
    TotalAmt = transaction.Amount,
    TotalAmtSpecified = true,
    Line = new[] 
    {
        new Line()
        {
            Amount = transaction.Amount,
            AmountSpecified = true,
            Description = transaction.DisplayBody,
            DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.SalesItemLineDetail,
            DetailTypeSpecified = true,
            AnyIntuitObject = new SalesItemLineDetail()
            {
                ItemRef = new ReferenceType(){
                    Value = qboIntegration.IncomeAccountId,
                    name = GetIncomeAccountName(),
                },
                Qty = 1,
                QtySpecified = true,
                TaxInclusiveAmt = transaction.Amount,
                TaxInclusiveAmtSpecified = true,
                ServiceDate = transaction.TransactionDate,
                ServiceDateSpecified = true,
            },
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting quickbooks.  It is not possible with the current iteration (V3) of the api.  They are considering adding this in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this using .net sdk. You can try the following ( Ref - [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542914/ipp-net-sdk-for-quickbooks-v3-0-create-invoice-error-bad-request)).

```
AnyIntuitObject = new SalesItemLineDetail()
    {
        ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.UnitPrice,
        AnyIntuitObject = amount,
        ...
    },
    DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.SalesItemLineDetail
```

- To get the correct object structure you can create a salesReceipt from QBO UI(with desired attribute value) and retrieve the same using getById endpoint.

To do the above, you can use the ApiExplorer tool as well.

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The apiexplorer is giving me 500 internal server errors.  I've contacted qbo directly.